# Why is the new Gutenberg editor so narrow, and how to make it wider?

Tags: block-editor, columns, post-editor

I'm beginning to like Gutenberg, but I find it too narrow, particularly when working with the 'Columns' block. Why is it so narrow, and can it safely be made wider? I could try doing so with CSS, but I thought it best to ask first, to avoid potential trouble.

Answer (score 3):

A functionality for wider layouts with Gutenberg Blocks is already supported officially by Wordpress. Just add the 'align-wide' theme support option to your theme setup function.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', function() { 
    add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
} );
```

You'll now see an option to use a wide/full width layouts when editing Gutenberg Blocks

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, add this to the end of your themes `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'wp_blocks_fullwidth');

function wp_blocks_fullwidth() {
    echo '<style>
        .wp-block {
            max-width: unset;
         }
    </style>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I changed 'unset' to '80%' or '1200px'. ;unset' would make it too wide touching left and right of the screen. Only problem is when theme update comes the function.php gets reverted and i lost the width again. anyway to make it permanent?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that comes to mind is to disable the options sidebar on the right. Just click on the cog icon and it will disappear, giving you 30px more space or so.

In addition, you can enter fullscreen mode by clicking on on the three vertical dots in the upper right corner all the way on the side and the choosing the respective option. This will disable the WordPress menu.

Not sure if that is enough for your purpose but it's what's available.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't answer why it's so narrow and how to make it wider. I didn't notice the extra 30px, but that's not nearly enough anyway. The options sidebar is a good deal wider than that. And Fullscreen mode just creates more empty space around the editor. What gives? There must be a reason for this setup. I have found a plugin, "Editor Full Width Gutenberg", that uses CSS to widen the editor. It looks fragile though, as it seems the author just hunted for CSS classes to override, and he already found that they changed between WP versions. I would like a robust solution.

Comment: Yeah, as I said these are the only native solutions that I am aware of. If you want more space than that, I am afraid you might have to get your hands dirty. At first glance, I haven't found any CSS that would make this easy to accomplish so I am afraid I'm of no further use here. Good luck to you anyway. Sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and couldn't figure it out but once I nested my content inside a container, I could then view content full width in the Gutenberg editor.

[image]